# Centering an image in the header

Tags: css

This is really weird. I had an img link to my home page but I can't get it to center. I finally wrapped it in a div and it centered. But now I can't click it as a link. If I closed the div class="img" tag then it won't center but I  can click it. It was centered before I started styling the form and didn't need a wrapper. I know there are other questions pertaining to centering an img, but I am at a complete loss. I tried text-aligning the header and then the img but still it won't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".block" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
    $(".link").toggle();
});
});
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="contact_us.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<header>
            <div class="img"<a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl"><img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/></a></div>
</header>
<div class="block">

    <span class="collapse-arrow">
    <span class="two"></span>
    <span class="one"></span>

     </span>

    <div class="link" style="display:none">
     <ul>

  <li> <a href=”http://www.cloudhudl.com”>Home</a> </li>
  <li><a href=”http://www.cloudhudl.com/about-us”>About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href=http://www.cloudhudl.com/contact-us>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <section id="main">
        <p>Have questions about what exactly Cloud Hudl is? How to get involved or what we hope to change about the industry? 
        Or something completely unrelated? Fill out the form below and we'll get back with you ASAP! A real person will reach
         out within one business day (Really!).</p>
</section>

    <section id="info">
        <p>Email: info@cloudhudl.com</p>
        <p>Phone: (620) 605-2154</p>
<!-- Social media BUT REPLACE PICTURES!! -->
    <a target="_blank" title="follow us on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/CloudHudl"><img alt="follow us on Facebook" src="https://c866088.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/assets/facebook40x40.png" border="0"></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="follow us on Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cloud-hudl"><img alt="Follow us on Linkedin" src="linkedin.png" border="0"></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="Follow us on Twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/cloudhudl"><img alt=Follow us on Twitter" src="twitter.png" border="0"></a>   

    </section>

    <form action="confirmation.htm" method="post" class="basic-grey">
        <div id="form">
    <span>Your Name :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Message :</span>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message to Us"></textarea>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label>    
</div>
</form>

    <footer>
        <address>
            Copyright 2015 &#169;
            (620) 605-2154
        </address>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.link{
    padding-bottom: 50px; 

}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    color:red;
}

li {
     float: left;
    display: inline;
}
body{



}
h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 30px 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
}
p{
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    color: #ddd;
}
b{
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}
/* we use a block as example */
.block{
    width: 480px;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
}

.block.active{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.collapse-arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto 10px;

    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
}

.collapse-arrow .one, .collapse-arrow .two{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 26px;
    top: 6px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .6s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .6s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.collapse-arrow .one{
    left: -1px;
    transform: rotate(32deg)
}
.collapse-arrow .two{
    right: -1px;
    transform: rotate(-32deg)
}

.active .collapse-arrow .one{transform: rotate(-32deg)} 
.active .collapse-arrow .two{transform: rotate(32deg)}

.collapse-arrow.black span{background: #111;}

//Form styles
/* Basic Grey */
#form {
postion: relative;
}
.basic-grey {
    position:absolute;
    top:55%;
    right:0;
    left:50%;
    width: 45%;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #888;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
    border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.basic-grey label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
}
.basic-grey label>span {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #888;
}
.basic-grey input[type="text"], .basic-grey input[type="email"], .basic-grey textarea {
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    color: #888;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
    padding: 5px 3px 3px 5px;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
    height:100px;
}
.basic-grey .button {
    background: #E27575;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #B6B6B6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9E3F3F;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-grey .button:hover {
    background: #CF7A7A
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your HTML. The `div.img` tag does not close properly. `<div class="img"<a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com"` should be `<div class="img"><a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com"`

Comment: As I mentioned I tried closing the div but it isn't centered if I do so. Test the code and it clearly doesn't work with the tag closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the div wrapper and, instead, you can add a class to your img tag.

Solution:

```css
.center { margin: 0 auto; display: block; }
```

```html
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="">
                <img class="center" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-9/256/teddy-bear-icon.png" width="40%"/>
            </a>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason this does not center it. It changes the size of the width but left-aligns the image.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3ueJyncJ7eaUpKQXB3TWZNQTg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing `>` after `<div class="img"`. Should be `<div class="img">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="img"<a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl"><img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/></a></div>
```

to

```
<div class="img"> <a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl"><img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <div class="img"
        <a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl">
            <img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

---

```
<img alt=Follow us on Twitter" src="twitter.png" border="0">
```

The above is not correct markup. The `<div>` tag should be properly closed, including the `alt` attribute. Like so:

```
<header>
    <div class="img">
        <a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl">
            <img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

---

```
<img alt="Follow us on Twitter" src="twitter.png" border="0">
```

Here is an example of it working

```css
.img {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.link{
    padding-bottom: 50px; 

}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    color:red;
}

li {
     float: left;
    display: inline;
}
body{



}
h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 30px 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
}
p{
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    color: #ddd;
}
b{
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}
/* we use a block as example */
.block{
    width: 480px;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
}

.block.active{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.collapse-arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto 10px;

    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
}

.collapse-arrow .one, .collapse-arrow .two{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 26px;
    top: 6px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .6s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .6s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.collapse-arrow .one{
    left: -1px;
    transform: rotate(32deg)
}
.collapse-arrow .two{
    right: -1px;
    transform: rotate(-32deg)
}

.active .collapse-arrow .one{transform: rotate(-32deg)} 
.active .collapse-arrow .two{transform: rotate(32deg)}

.collapse-arrow.black span{background: #111;}

//Form styles
/* Basic Grey */
#form {
postion: relative;
}
.basic-grey {
    position:absolute;
    top:55%;
    right:0;
    left:50%;
    width: 45%;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #888;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
    border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.basic-grey label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
}
.basic-grey label>span {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #888;
}
.basic-grey input[type="text"], .basic-grey input[type="email"], .basic-grey textarea {
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    color: #888;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
    padding: 5px 3px 3px 5px;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
    height:100px;
}
.basic-grey .button {
    background: #E27575;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #B6B6B6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9E3F3F;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-grey .button:hover {
    background: #CF7A7A
}

.img a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".block" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
    $(".link").toggle();
});
});
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="contact_us.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<header>
            <div class="img"><a href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl"><img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/></a></div>
</header>
<div class="block">

    <span class="collapse-arrow">
    <span class="two"></span>
    <span class="one"></span>

     </span>

    <div class="link" style="display:none">
     <ul>

  <li> <a href=”http://www.cloudhudl.com”>Home</a> </li>
  <li><a href=”http://www.cloudhudl.com/about-us”>About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href=http://www.cloudhudl.com/contact-us>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <section id="main">
        <p>Have questions about what exactly Cloud Hudl is? How to get involved or what we hope to change about the industry? 
        Or something completely unrelated? Fill out the form below and we'll get back with you ASAP! A real person will reach
         out within one business day (Really!).</p>
</section>

    <section id="info">
        <p>Email: info@cloudhudl.com</p>
        <p>Phone: (620) 605-2154</p>
<!-- Social media BUT REPLACE PICTURES!! -->
    <a target="_blank" title="follow us on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/CloudHudl"><img alt="follow us on Facebook" src="https://c866088.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/assets/facebook40x40.png" border="0"></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="follow us on Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cloud-hudl"><img alt="Follow us on Linkedin" src="linkedin.png" border="0"></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="Follow us on Twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/cloudhudl"><img alt="Follow us on Twitter" src="twitter.png" border="0"></a>   

    </section>

    <form action="confirmation.htm" method="post" class="basic-grey">
        <div id="form">
    <span>Your Name :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Message :</span>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message to Us"></textarea>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label>    
</div>
</form>

    <footer>
        <address>
            Copyright 2015 &#169;
            (620) 605-2154
        </address>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The arrow below the logo will be off-centered when the width of the viewport is below `480px` due to the class `.block` having a fixed width of `480px`, removing the `width` from `.block` will solve that.

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned I tried closing the div but it isn't centered if I do so. Test the code and it clearly doesn't work with the tag closed.

Comment: @CameronHall With the suggested change above, change `display: block` to `display: inline-block` on your `<a>` element that contains the logo. I noticed you already tried `text-align: center`, it should work then, no?

Comment: This does work except that it centers the left side instead of from the middle. I'm assuming text-align isn't the best way of doing this now.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `text-align: center` if you do not know the width of the logo. If you would give the logo a `width` you could set the logo element to `margin: auto;` and it will center too. Could you expand on it centering from the left? I am not sure if I fully understand.

Comment: Margin auto is having the same effect. I mean the left side is in the center of the page and the image is therefore off-center to the right. Instead of the center of the image being positioned in the center of the page.

Comment: @CameronHall I will update my post, but to me the logo seems perfectly centered, the arrow below is not centered however at lower resolutions. The `alt` attribute is also not properly closed here: `<img alt=Follow us on Twitter" src="twitter.png" border="0">`

Comment: It might look like the arrow is the on off centered but if I center the arrow under the logo they are both set to the right not the center. I don't know why it looks different for you but for me the img is defiantly set to the right. The logo img has a character in the middle which makes it a little easier to see the difference.

Comment: @CameronHall At what size are you viewing this at? That is odd. Can you maybe remove the default `width: 480px` from the `.block` class? This indeed puts the arrow to the right at smaller resolutions. I have added an image which illustrates this.

Comment: I'll have to play with it but removing the width screws with the alignment of  the links. Also, the image is still off center at a normal size.

Comment: Did you check the included code snippet @CameronHall it works here. Which browser are you using if I may ask?

Comment: Not saying the arrow isn't centered... I'm saying the links displayed after clicking the arrow do not display correctly. Plus the img is still not centered. I have tried Chrome and IE both.

Comment: Also, if I use the code you used then the img is align at the left. I don't know why but I am using the exact same code as you have in the snippet.

Comment: @CameronHall For the links: remove `float: left` from the `<li>` element that wraps around the link and add `display: inline-block;`  :-)

Comment: This still doesn't fix the header image.

Comment: @CameronHall can you add an image of what you're currently seeing? It is difficult for me to see due to none of the images being linked.

Comment: I changed it to 0 auto margin and give it a width. Works fine for the big screen.

Answer (score 0):

here is the issue :

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    color:red;
}
```

close the *div tag* and remove `display: block;` from the global css *link tag* :

```css
a {
    /*display: block;*/
    width: 80px;
    color:red;
}
```

```css
.img {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.link{
    padding-bottom: 50px; 

}
a {
    /*display: block;*/
    width: 80px;
    color:red;
}

li {
     float: left;
    display: inline;
}
body{



}
h1{
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 30px 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
}
p{
    font-size:18px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    color: #ddd;
}
b{
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}
/* we use a block as example */
.block{
    width: 480px;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
    transition: all .7s ease;
}

.block.active{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.collapse-arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto 10px;

    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
}

.collapse-arrow .one, .collapse-arrow .two{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 26px;
    top: 6px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .6s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .6s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.collapse-arrow .one{
    left: -1px;
    transform: rotate(32deg)
}
.collapse-arrow .two{
    right: -1px;
    transform: rotate(-32deg)
}

.active .collapse-arrow .one{transform: rotate(-32deg)} 
.active .collapse-arrow .two{transform: rotate(32deg)}

.collapse-arrow.black span{background: #111;}

//Form styles
/* Basic Grey */
#form {
postion: relative;
}
.basic-grey {
    position:absolute;
    top:55%;
    right:0;
    left:50%;
    width: 45%;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 25px 15px 25px 10px;
    font: 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #888;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
    border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
.basic-grey label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
}
.basic-grey label>span {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #888;
}
.basic-grey input[type="text"], .basic-grey input[type="email"], .basic-grey textarea {
    border: 1px solid #DADADA;
    color: #888;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height:15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
    padding: 5px 3px 3px 5px;
}
.basic-grey textarea{
    height:100px;
}
.basic-grey .button {
    background: #E27575;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #B6B6B6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9E3F3F;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-grey .button:hover {
    background: #CF7A7A
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".block" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
    $(".link").toggle();
});
});
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link href="contact_us.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<header>
            <div class="img"><a class="img" href="http://www.cloudhudl.com" alt="Cloud Hudl"><img src="white_logo.png" alt="Cloud Hudl"/></a></div>
</header>
<div class="block">

    <span class="collapse-arrow">
    <span class="two"></span>
    <span class="one"></span>

     </span>

    <div class="link" style="display:none">
     <ul>

  <li> <a href=”http://www.cloudhudl.com”>Home</a> </li>
  <li><a href=”http://www.cloudhudl.com/about-us”>About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href=http://www.cloudhudl.com/contact-us>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <section id="main">
        <p>Have questions about what exactly Cloud Hudl is? How to get involved or what we hope to change about the industry? 
        Or something completely unrelated? Fill out the form below and we'll get back with you ASAP! A real person will reach
         out within one business day (Really!).</p>
</section>

    <section id="info">
        <p>Email: info@cloudhudl.com</p>
        <p>Phone: (620) 605-2154</p>
<!-- Social media BUT REPLACE PICTURES!! -->
    <a target="_blank" title="follow us on Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/CloudHudl"><img alt="follow us on Facebook" src="https://c866088.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/assets/facebook40x40.png" border="0"></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="follow us on Linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cloud-hudl"><img alt="Follow us on Linkedin" src="linkedin.png" border="0"></a>
    <a target="_blank" title="Follow us on Twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/cloudhudl"><img alt=Follow us on Twitter" src="twitter.png" border="0"></a>   

    </section>

    <form action="confirmation.htm" method="post" class="basic-grey">
        <div id="form">
    <span>Your Name :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Message :</span>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message to Us"></textarea>
    </label> 
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label>    
</div>
</form>

    <footer>
        <address>
            Copyright 2015 &#169;
            (620) 605-2154
        </address>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove display: block from a and img.

```
img {
    /* display: block; */
    /* margin: auto; */
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    /* display: block; */
    /* width: 80px; */
    color:red;
}
```